# How change color of dotted line in mxgraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, mxgraph

I want to change the color of dotted line from black to red when we drag a vertex

**Question:** I want to change dotted line color to red from black while drag

Here is how it appears on drag

[image]

I tried to find the dashed color on drag in mxConstants but i did not find it

```js
function main(container)
        {
            // Checks if the browser is supported
            if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
            {
                // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
                mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
            }
            else
            {
                // Disables the built-in context menu
                mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);
                
                // Creates the graph inside the given container
                var graph = new mxGraph(container);

                // Enables rubberband selection
                new mxRubberband(graph);
                
                // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
                // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
                var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
                                
                // Adds cells to the model in a single step
                graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello,', 20, 20, 80, 30);

                }
                finally
                {
                    // Updates the display
                    graph.getModel().endUpdate();
                }
            }
        };
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Toolbar example for mxGraph</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
    </script>
    <script src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="main(document.getElementById('graphContainer'))">


    <div id="graphContainer">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You are using `insertVertex` and it is difficult to change preview of drag object. If you use `mxUtils.makeDraggable` I have a solution for what you want

Comment: in my actual project i'm using `mxUtils.makeDraggable`  please post your solution i will accept your answer.

BUT remember the solution must work on canvas

Comment: outside canvas i have solution too.    on canvas it does not make any difference whether i'm using `insertVertex` or anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/issues/103) you can do that by below code:

```
mxGraphHandler.prototype.previewColor = 'red';
```

Working snippet:

```js
function main(container)
        {
      mxGraphHandler.prototype.previewColor = 'red';
    
            // Checks if the browser is supported
            if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported())
            {
                // Displays an error message if the browser is not supported.
                mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
            }
            else
            {
                // Disables the built-in context menu
                mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);
                
                // Creates the graph inside the given container
                var graph = new mxGraph(container);

                // Enables rubberband selection
                new mxRubberband(graph);
                
                // Gets the default parent for inserting new cells. This
                // is normally the first child of the root (ie. layer 0).
                var parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
                                
                // Adds cells to the model in a single step
                graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
                try
                {
                    var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'Hello,', 20, 20, 80, 30);

                }
                finally
                {
                    // Updates the display
                    graph.getModel().endUpdate();
                }
            }
        };
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Toolbar example for mxGraph</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        mxBasePath = 'https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src';
    </script>
    <script src="https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="main(document.getElementById('graphContainer'))">


    <div id="graphContainer">

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: on canvas it is still black. please check once.  it should be red on canvas

Comment: @Learner No it's red. check the snippet or show me picture of you are seeing

Comment: on black can if you drag it is coming as black

Comment: In my snippet you mean? when drag it on black canvas?

Comment: @Learner It red for me I show a picture right now

Comment: first time on dragging from outside it is red, on canvas it is black!!

Comment: @Learner Please check my answer I upload a picture for you. As you see it is red even on black canvas for first time, second time and ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235682/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-learner).

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Learner Not yet. all documentation said that you can create `createDragPreview` But there is nothing about moving in canvas preview.

Comment: i suspect its style to be there in `mxConstants`

Comment: Maybe. The only thing I found it is `mxGraphHandler.prototype.createPreviewShape`. see https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/issues/103

Comment: with your help i found a solution `mxGraphHandler.prototype.previewColor = 'red';`  so please provide your answer with this simple line

Comment: could you please have a look at one of the trickiest question on `mxgraph` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676901/how-to-determine-which-side-of-connection-is-connected-in-mxgraph